# Postgres one to many query, returning array of objects, with another array of objects inside

Tags: postgresql

I'm building a full stack web app that has a postgres database, and contains an *organisation* table, and a *vendor* table.
There can only be one organisation, whilst there can be many vendors, every vendor must be linked to one organisation, and there can be many vendors that are linked to the same organisation. I.e:

[image]

I'm using node/express to handle the backend API, with the results of the query being returned in the json format - response.json(res.rows).

I need to return a single array of objects that contains all organisation IDs, and the associated organisation names, then inside each organisation I need an array to list of all vendor IDs, and vendor names.
Something like this to be returned:

[image]

I hope that makes sense :/

Comment: Look like it's a case of the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function. But I'm not familiar with postgres to provide the exact code.

Comment: bump, can anybody help with this?